# Android OpenGL reading pixel color at the center of the screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm rendering a texture in OpenGL. I want to retrieve the pixel color value at the center of the screen.

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
GLES20.glFinish();
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
byteBuffer.get(byteArray);
int r = ((int) byteArray[0]) & 0xFF;
int g = ((int) byteArray[1]) & 0xFF;
int b = ((int) byteArray[2]) & 0xFF;
String key = r + " " + g + " " + b;
Log.i(TAG, key);
```

As a test, I'm rendering a red square to the center of the screen, and expect to log (255 0 0) but I only get back (255 0 0) when I render the entire screen red.

Comment: Why do you expect to get the center if your read the pixel at the bottom-left corner?

Comment: Does GLES20.glReadPixels() not use the OpenGL coordinate system? (0, 0) is the center of the screen in OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates/sizes passed to `glReadPixels()` are in window coordinates. The window coordinate system has its origin in the lower left corner of the window, with a unit of pixels.

This is not to be confused with the NDC (normalized device coordinates) system used for vertex coordinates, which has its origin in the center of the window, and has a range of [-1.0, 1.0] in both the x- and y-directions.

So in your example:

```
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1,
    GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
```

you are reading one pixel in the lower left corner of the rendering surface. To read a pixel in the center, you need:

```
GLES20.glReadPixels(width / 2, height / 2, 1, 1,
    GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
```

where `width` and `height` are the dimensions of the rendering surface in pixels.